# how to create a SQL database from a csv file in Python

Tags: python, database, csv, mysql-python

I need to load in a large dataset (20gb for now but will be 100 gb in the future) from a csv file. I am using the MySQLdb module in python (PyCharm). I also need to only select some certain columns. So far I have tried this:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    db='mydb')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('collected_quotes_sample.csv'))
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(RIC, Date, Time, Ask, Bid, BAS, window ) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

but it provides many errors. I am new to python and SQL database so I am not familiar with the commands/codes. So I have a few questions:

```
1. with MySQLdb.connect( host,user,passwd,db etc), what are host, user, password etc? to my understanding, they are credentials for my account in the computer. so do I need to put in my user account and password?
2. What does mydb.cursor do?
3. How to upload a csv file into a SQL database? and after the database is created, I can write a python script to work on it and there is no need to re read/create the database?
```

Thanks a lots!

Comment: Do you actually have a MySQL server setup on localhost?

Comment: that python MySQLdb is just a client that can connect to real mysql server

Comment: @Keatinge I dont think I have MySQL server setup. How can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions

> 1. with MySQLdb.connect( host,user,passwd,db etc), what are host, user, password etc? to my understanding, they are credentials for my
>      account in the computer. so do I need to put in my user account and
>      password?

- **Answer**: host is the server IP address + the port num. user/pwd is the client user you created on the server side. And one host can have many DB created inside, so you need to specify the DB. Usually when you started, you are likely using the `localhost`(127.0.0.1), and the port number is what you defined when you create the server. Once the server is started, one or more clients can be connected to the database server. You then need to have a superuser (like `root`) with all the privileges and several other normal users (probably with less privileges).

> 2. What does mydb.cursor do?

- **Answer**: cursor is a object that can execute operations such as SQL statements. You always need Cursor objects interact with the MySQL server. If you are using native SQL script to interact with the MySQL server, you don't really need this `cursor` object, but since you are using MySQLdb as a Python wrapper, then you need to use it as the DB-API requires that you interface to them that way (The cursor object is an abstraction specified in the Python DB-API 2.0).

> 3. How to upload a csv file into a SQL database? and after the database is created, I can write a python script to work on it and
>      there is no need to re read/create the database?

- **Answer**: Generally, the code you shown in the question is performing the uploading process. So once you uploaded successfully, you can then retrieve it later by implementing some SQL retrieving statement in your Python by using MySQLdb. Once the DB is created, you will rarely need to re-create unless you would like to delete all your old data. And to work with it, you would always need to `read` from the DB. But you can put the commonly used SQL (or call some stored function/procedure) into your Python code so that you can just call one function to retrieve the data in the way you want.

Generally, I think you should understand [more about MySQL basics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html) before rushing to use them. And also how to [Install MySQL on Windows](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/install-mysql/)

Comment: @duckman, you may want to go through the [MySQL Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/) first

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer, I really appreciate it. Can you please be a bit more specific on my codes on uploading data to a SQL database? In particular, I want to create a SQL database from a large csv file on my computer. How do I create a server? and do I need a username and password? or 'root' is ok for the username? and the 'localhost' in my code does not seem to work. Thank you very much

Comment: thanks for the tutorial link. I will go through them

Comment: @duckman, first of all, you must have a DB created already, so you can follow the tutorial link I sent to install the server on your localhost first. But as @jimifiki suggested, if you just want to `upload your data to some DB and play with it` without using advanced functions and really caring about the performance, you should just use `sqlite` as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an SQL db with Python just for the sake of playing with both languages, you should try SQLite:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("brand_new_db.db")
```

and you are done.

There are many tutorials on the web. [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/pdf/sqlite_python.pdf) for instance, could be a good starting point.

Comment: thanks, there are too many tutorial website and I dont know which one is good. Yours seems to be compact and short which is good. is there any differences between sqlite3 and MySQLdb module?

Comment: Sqlite, MySQL, Postgres,... are different RDMS Relational Database Management Systems. They are all based on SQL as language but they differ in the specific SQL syntax they implement. Moreover they dramatically differ in terms of performance. 

Once you start understanding both Python and SQL I strongly suggest you to get acquainted with SQLAlchemy.

Let me give you one more random link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems

Comment: how to define the table from csv after here? i am thinking about doing equivalent of following from sqlite prompt all via python: `.mode csv .import FILE.csv mydatabase`